# Read .obj File with Texture in WPF

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit, helix

I am trying to load `.obj` File using helix tool kit code. but i didn't get texture included that `.obj` file.

```
ObjReader studioreader = new ObjReader();

        Model3D m3d = studioreader.Read("Model/2 seat sofa .obj");

        Transform3DGroup transform = new Transform3DGroup();
        RotateTransform3D rotateTrans = new RotateTransform3D();
        rotateTrans.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 0);
        transform.Children.Add(rotateTrans);
        rotateTrans.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 0);
        transform.Children.Add(rotateTrans);
        TranslateTransform3D translateTrans = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 20, 0);

        transform.Children.Add(rotateTrans);
        transform.Children.Add(translateTrans);
        m3d.Transform = transform;
        group.Children.Add(m3d);
```

i am using this code for load `.obj` file. i get Mold of an object but what should i do to load texture